# how to use column and row inside card in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a flutter cards and inside of the card I'm trying to design something like the picture below using Column and row but not sure how to use both of them at the same time so it'll be really appreciated if somebody can help me on how to achieve this thing.

```
      Container(
        height: 100,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 8.0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 30,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('US Daily Retail Delieveries by Brand', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 20,),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(color: Colors.black,),
              Container(
                height: 30,
                child: new ListTile(
                  title: Text("Price")
                ),
              )
            ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, you need to work with Columns and Rows.

Try this code to visualize the layout, similar to your image.

I added some `Padding()` just to make room for the text.

You can put this inside the child of your `Card()` widget.

```
Column(children: [
      Row(children: [
         Text("Row 1"),
         Spacer(),
         Icon(Icons.account_box),
      ]),
      Row(children: [
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text("Data 1 Title"),
              Text("Data 1.1"),
              Text("Data 1.2"),
            ])),
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text("Data 2 Title"),
              Text("Data 2.1"),
              Text("Data 2.2"),
            ])),
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text("Data 3 Title"),
              Text("Data 3.1"),
              Text("Data 3.2"),
            ])),
        Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text("Data 4 Title"),
              Text("Data 4.1"),
              Text("Data 4.2"),
            ])),
      ]),
    ])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer. by any chance how should I add trailing icon to move to the left end side instead of using padding to move the icon. Also my verticalDivider is not appearing for some reason.

Comment: I have added a Spacer() and an Icon() in the code, for the first Row()

Answer (score 0):

So you could use Row and Column.
Your structure could look like this:

```
Column(
   children : [
       // A Row for the top
       Row(children: [ Text('Group Name'), Icon(Icons.icon)] ),
       //For the Line 
       Divider(height, thickness etc...),
       // A Row for each Row in the table from now on
       //VerticalDivider for the vertical line, just as Divider
       Row(children :[ Text('price1'),  VerticalDivider(), Text('1')],
       // be carefull with the $ since it's used to put variables 
       // into strings, eg Text('Name : $name ')
       ),
    ],
),
```

You could also use a Table Widget for this.

Comment: thanks for the answer. really appreciate for your help